# Copy/paste issue in CKEditor on IE 11 browser (update DLL)?

Tags: .net, ckeditor

We have issue of copy/paste (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) in CKEditor on IE 11 browser. The issue is paste function don't work on IE 11 browser, so where we can find upgraded CKEditor.NET.dll with IE 11 fixes?

If there is no upgraded DLL then when upgraded DLL will be available?

Answer (score 1):

The official downloads are found at http://ckeditor.com/download. The latest version you are looking for is 3.6.4 for ASP.NET. However, it does not contain the latest changes possible (such as the latest IE version support fixes) - the pure JS version is already at 4.2.3.

I would recommend moving away from the DLL version and switching to the pure JS version.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the js v 4.3 with the dll you have that will solve it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: maybe, I dont when the dll will be available but this is a way to update it yourself.